# Scala working with very large list

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have a List with about 1176^3 positions.
Making smth like

```
val x = list.length
```

takes hours ..

When in list is 1271256 positions is ok, just few seconds.
Any one have idea how to speed up it ?

Comment: If several seconds for ~1 million elements is ok for you, why you complain about hours for ~1 billion elements? Assuming that processing of 1271256 elements takes 5 seconds, processing of 1176^3 elements should take: time = 1176^3 / 1271256 * 5 = 6397 seconds = 1.78 hours.

Answer (score 9):

`List` is possibly the wrong data structure for a length operation as it is O(n) - it takes longer to complete the longer the list is.

[Vector](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Vector) is possibly a better data structure to use if you are needing to invoke `length` as its storage supports random access in a finite time.

This, of course, does not mean that List is a poor structure to use, just in this case it might not be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

To add to gpampara's answer, in cases like these you may actually be able to justify using an Array, since it has the lowest overhead per item stored and O(1) access to elements and length determination (since it's recorded in the array header itself).

Array has many down-sides, but I consider it justifiable when memory overhead is a primary consideration (and when a fixed-size collection whose size is known at the time of creation is feasible).